# NPM Install - package.json error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to create a local server for visual studio code through Node by following [Microsoft's Blog Post](https://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/visual-studio-code-and-local-web-server). I followed these very simple instructions exactly by adding a package.json file in my root folder and running npm install first. When I do, I get the following error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Temple\desktop\secret\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '“' at 2:4
npm ERR!    “name”: “Demo”,
npm ERR!    ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Temple\desktop\secret\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Temple\desktop\secret\npm-debug.log
```

And yes, I have node installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you copy pasted

```
"name": "Demo”,
```

it got changed to

```
“name”: “Demo”,
```

The problem is with the quotes. Replace all instances of `“` or `”` with `"`, and you should be good.

Comment: Dude, thank you! Never would have guessed, will put you as answer when the time limit is up. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong type of quotes ( windows type ) use this character : `"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you edited the `package.json` with an editor that automatically uses "smart quotes" (like Microsoft Word, for example). Try retyping the `“` characters in Notepad, for example, and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in you package.json
You must use double quotes.
Check and validate your package.json file in [here](https://jsonlint.com)